# How do I display results of an entire column based on specific phrase in a row using php & mysql?

Tags: php, html, mysql, apache2

So to better explain what I'm doing,

1. I'm trying to use php to query 1 table
2. Look if row 1 named "Site" matches my query
3. Then post the results of the entire column results

So I need to change my while statement to an if statement. Just a bit fuzzy on how to write it up so that it only posts every column that matches my query.

```
    $con=mysqli_connect("$host", "$username", "$password","$db_name");
    // Check connection
    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
      {
      echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
      }

    $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM table");

    while($info = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
      {
      echo " | ".$info['site']. " | " .$info['asset']. " | " .$info['hostname'].         " | " .$info['sys_name']. " | ". $info['ip']. " | ";

      echo "<br>";
      }
```

Comment: Can't you use a `WHERE` clause in your query to only select the specific row(s)? - `SELECT * FROM table WHERE site = 'your_value'`

Comment: SELECT * FROM table where Site = 'something' ??

Comment: I tried your suggestion but the site row might be be for instance might be named something like VANCOVER1, VANCOOVER2, VANCOOVER3 and all I want is it to show all that match VANCOOVER can I use a wildcard of some sort?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The wildcard in SQL is `%`. Everything before VANCOOVER or after it will be overlooked when VANCOOVER is written as `%VANCOOVER%`. In PHP, LIKE `%$Search%`

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE site LIKE '%VANCOOVER%'
```

Comment: Although this answers the question, more information could be included that would help this user better understand SQL.

Comment: The wildcard in SQL is '%'. Everything before VANCOOVER or after it will be overlooked when VANCOOVER is written as "%VANCOOVER%". In PHP, LIKE '%$Search%'.